# Download full website image from google app engine?

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

We use a Flexible Environment with Google App Engine for our PHP Website (Laravel) and cannot figure out how to download current website image from Google App Engine with flexible environment setup. As I now have a new developer, we need this latest version for a backup purpose and for future improvement. The idea is to get the latest code from there and also the database, which is even more important, as website already has data and users on it (it is live now, in beta).

We also have a GitHub account setup. If we could load an image from the cloud to GitHub, that could work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to find the source code here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/debug

Alternatively, since you are using GAE Flex, you could ssh into your instance to try to find it:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance

As for the Database, the answer depends on 1) which database you are using (google datastore vs google cloud sql, etc) and 2) what you intend to do with it.

For example, Google datastore has datastore admin which can retrieve a snapshot of the database (https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/settings), but the output is not something standard like csv. It's primarily used for backups & restores. But you can use this to clone your database into another app engine project

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy anything from a VM on google Cloud platform, you first need to access the docker via SSH (command: sudo docker exec -it gaeapp /bin/bash). When inside of docker, you need to archive everything you need into TAR.GZ format (or try rar or zip, my server only supported TAR.GZ), once archived, you need to copy that outside of docker, which i already forgot how I have done that (oops). But google will help. Once done there will be a very non obvious gear icon on your SSH window top right where you can simply click download file and enter a file name. Choose your archive and vuala.